# ¿Cómo evitar doble ejecución de un botón tipo submit en HTML y PHP?

Tags: php, html

Mi problema es que al darle doble clic a un botón me inserta dos veces a la base de datos. Si solo le doy un clic me inserta una vez, normal. ¿Cómo puedo evitarlo sin validar los datos repetidos en la base de datos?

Gracias de antemano.

PHP:

```
include 'db-connection.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   //Add new state
   if (isset($_POST['btnAddState'])) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
            
      $sql = "INSERT INTO states (name) VALUES ('$name')";
      $query = mysqli_query($connectionString, $sql);
            
      if (!$query) {
         echo "<script>alert('Ha ocurrido un error al agregar el estado.');
         window.location.href = 'addresses.php';
         </script>";
      } else {
         echo "<script>alert('El estado se ha agregado correctamente.');
         window.location.href = 'addresses.php';
         </script>";
      }

      mysqli_close($connectionString);
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <label class="mt-2" for="name"><b>NOMBRE:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-1">
        <button type="submit" id="btnAddState" name="btnAddState" class="btn btn-success col-sm-4 col-5 mx-1"><i class="fas fa-save mr-2"></i> Guardar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-4 col-5 mx-1" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times mr-2"></i> Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Y el codigo que estas usando edgard ??

Comment: @Excorpion listo

Comment: Eso es todo el html?

Comment: Creo que es suficiente para que sepan cómo envío la info

Comment: Si pero no tiene que ver con eso. Tiene que ver con si recarga la pagina o no por errores de html.

Comment: no seria un problema en si, ya que si el formulario no se ha recargado y le sigues dando click, este insertara tantos datos como halla dado click, lo que puedes hacer es mandarlo desde JavaScript, puedes usar el double click para arreglar el detalle.

Comment: Mira así  no te  den doble click pero escriban el mismo  nombrey apellido lo vas a duplicar. Mejor es validar antes de insertar y así te protejes de donde venga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y si le agregas con `js` para que una vez que se haga `click` en el `botón` le agregue la `class` `disable` de `bootstrap` que eso hace que se bloquee y no se de mas click, obvio pasando primero por las verificaciones previas porque sino va causar de que si no completo como corresponde igual se va agregar la `class`, te dejo como lo implemente yo.

```js
function myFunction() {
                if ($('#name').val() !== undefined && $('#name').val().trim() == '') {
                    alert('Ingresá un Nombre');
                    return;
                }
                $('#btnAddState').addClass("disabled");
                
            }
```

```html
<form>
        <label class="mt-2" for="name"><b>NOMBRE:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
        <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-1">
            <button type="submit" id="btnAddState" name="btnAddState" class="btn btn-success col-sm-4 col-5 mx-1" onclick="myFunction()">Guardar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-4 col-5 mx-1" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times mr-2"></i> Cancelar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Me funcionó amigo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

No esta insertando doble por presionar dos veces el botón. Esta insertando una vez cuando entras a la pagina  y otra vez al presionar el botón (recargar la pagina).

Utiliza el metodo `isset`   y asignale un `name` al boton

```html
 <button type="submit" name="btnguardar">Guardar</button>
```

Luego en la pagina utiliza el siguiente metodo.

```html
if(isset($_POST['btnguardar'])){

   include 'db-conexion.php';
    
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    
    if (!$query) {
       echo "Error al insertar";
    } else {
       echo "Insertado correctamente";
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    
}
```

Así te aseguras que el script para guardar solo se ejecuta cuando presionas el botón  y no cuando entras a la pagina y/o recargas

------------------------Edito------------------------
También
Podrías desactivar el botón con jquery  puedes ver el ejemplo completo [aqui](https://www.scotsscripts.com/blog/how-to-disable-double-click-on-submit-button.html)

```
<button type="submit" id="submitbutton" onclick="document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = true;document.getElementById('submitbutton').style.opacity='0.5';">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: De hecho así lo tengo amigo, ya edité la pregunta para añadir un mejor ejemplo. Aún así me agrega dos veces al dar doble clic

Comment: He editado la respuesta